# unable to send emails to gmail using sendmail 550-5.7.26 error

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, sendmail

The domain isn't registered with the same host though, so I'm using custom nameservers. and when I send emails like this :

```
sendmail mytest@gmail.com
this is a test.
.
```

I get this error :

```
(reason: 550-5.7.26 This mail has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated.)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-5.7.26 This mail has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated.
<<< 550-5.7.26 Gmail requires all senders to authenticate with either SPF or DKIM.
<<< 550-5.7.26 
<<< 550-5.7.26  Authentication results:
<<< 550-5.7.26  DKIM = did not pass
<<< 550-5.7.26  SPF [194.135.94.254] with ip: [194.135.94.254] = did not pass
<<< 550-5.7.26 
<<< 550-5.7.26  For instructions on setting up authentication, go to
<<< 550 5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication u20-20020a05651206

...skipping 1 line
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

When I use email checker online tools like this one:

[mxtoolbox.com](https://mxtoolbox.com)

I get this result which says I have spf :

[SPF check results](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%website.com&run=toolpage)

I have also created DKIM records with `default` selector and this is the result :

[DKIM check results](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dkim%website.com%3Adefault&run=toolpage)

Also, when I use email health checker :

[Health Checker](https://mxtoolbox.com/emailhealth/website.com/)

one of the errors says :

```
smtp    website.com Failed To Connect
```

content of `mail.log`when I send email to `unreturner@gmail.com`

```
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 sendmail[347972]: 41A1oMOk347972: from=tmc, size=6, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202402100150.41A1oMOk347972@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud>, relay=tmc@localhost
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 sm-mta[347973]: 41A1oNCO347973: from=<tmc@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud>, size=295, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202402100150.41A1oMOk347972@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=website.com [127.0.0.1]
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 opendkim[312964]: 41A1oNCO347973: no signing table match for 'tmc@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud'
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 opendkim[312964]: 41A1oNCO347973: no signature data
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 sendmail[347972]: 41A1oMOk347972: to=unreturner@gmail.com, ctladdr=tmc (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30006, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (41A1oNCO347973 Message accepted for delivery)
Feb 10 03:50:23 1cr0 sm-mta[347975]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
Feb 10 03:50:24 1cr0 sm-mta[347975]: 41A1oNCO347973: to=<unreturner@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<tmc@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120295, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [64.233.164.27], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Feb 10 03:50:24 1cr0 sm-mta[347975]: 41A1oNCO347973: 41A1oOCO347975: DSN: Service unavailable
Feb 10 03:50:24 1cr0 sm-mta[347975]: 41A1oOCO347975: to=<tmc@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Not sure why it says no signing table, even though I configured opendkim based on this tutorial :

[Tutorial for configuring opendkim](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/technical-notes/356-setting-up-dkim-with-sendmail)

And I have configured `sendmail` based on this tutorial :

[Configuring sendmail tutorial](https://kenfavors.com/code/how-to-install-and-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu/)

Any idea why gmail still says I didn't pass the SPF or DKIM?

Answer (score 3):

You are sending an email from the address `tmc@1cr0.l.hostens.cloud`. The domain `1cr0.l.hostens.cloud` doesn't match your `website.com`.